# Issue in removing element from JList

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I have a problem in removing an element from a JList, my application is a client server application, the client has the JList (The view). The server have the actual data of the JList in the form of vector. When a certain action occurs on the client the server has to remove an element from the vector and then update the view on the client. I tried to get the vector after removing from the server and then construct a new JList, then set it at the view, but no update occurs.

What are some possible ways to do that?

note: i used the DefaultListModel like that:

```
DefaultListModel model=(DefaultListModel)myList.getModel();
model.removeElement(myElement);
myList.setModel(model);
```

but it gives a ClassCastException at runtime, it says that `javax.swing.JList cannot be cast to javax.swing.DefaultListModel`

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add elements to a list by just passing it a `Vector` in the constructor or using the `setListData` method, but that is not the best way to do it.

You would usually want to use a `ListModel` implementation like `DefaultListModel`. It defines methods for handling data (`addElement`, `removeElement`,...).

You could reduce the amount of exchanged data between the server and the client(s) by querying the server for the removed element only and not getting all the data.

**Update**: Now I see you are using a model. The default implementation of a `JList` model is not of type `DefaultListModel`. You can set the model in the `JList` constructor, when you instantiate your `JList` at the beginning.

```
DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
JList list = new JList(model);
```

Don't instantiate it again, you need to do that only once. Then, you can use the code you posted, but you don't have to call the `setModel()` method after you remove an element.

Comment: i don't want to construct a new JList, i want to get the model of the existing list in order to remove element from it, but when i do that a class cast exception occurs!

Comment: When you instantiate your JList at the beginning, instantiate it with a DefaultListModel in the constructor. I never told you to construct a new one when you update it.

Comment: i construct it at the begging with a vector, is it a must to construct it with a DefaultListModel, in other words, how to remove element from a JList that initialy constructed with a vector ?

Comment: If you really want to do it that way then you will have to call list.setListData with the updated Vector as a parameter. However, I suggest you use the approach I mentioned in my answer. Add data to the DefaultListModel and remove it from there.